# vue.js 2.0 communication best practice

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue-component, vue.js

I am currently working on some stuff with vue.js and would like to ask if the following is good practice.

I have a parent and a child component, for instance dropdown and dropdown-item. When a dropdown-item gets selected I change via `this.$parent.dropdown.selected`the selected item. Is this good practice or should I go via events?

Here is the code:

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"  @click="toggle" type="button">
      {{dropdown.selected.text}}
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" v-show="!isClosed">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DropdownItem from './dropdown-item.vue'

class Dropdown{
  constructor(name, selected, displayedItems) {
    this.name = name
    this.selected = new DropdownItem.uiClass("",selected)
    this.displayedItems = displayedItems
  }
}

export default {
  uiClass: Dropdown,
  name: "ui-dropdown",
  data() {
    return {
      isClosed: true
    }
  },
  props:{
    dropdown: Dropdown
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.isClosed = !this.isClosed
    }
  }
}
```

```
<template lang="html">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" @click.stop.prevent="select()"
    v-bind:class="{ 'active': value == $parent.dropdown.selected.value }">
    {{text}}
  </a>
</template>

<script>
class DropdownItem {
  constructor(value,text) {
    this.value = value
    this.text = text
  }
}

export default {
  uiClass: DropdownItem,
  name: "ui-dropdown-item",
  props:{
    value: String,
    text: String
  },
  computed: {
    dropdownItem() {
      return new DropdownItem(this.value, this.text)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    select() {
      this.$parent.dropdown.selected = this.dropdownItem;
      this.$parent.toggle()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Thank you for your response

Comment: Really differs on your application size. In case when u have medium to large application. Then it much more prefferable if u will use event driven development or vuex.

Comment: @GONG Ok, thank you very much for that input!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vue.js/5941/events/20840/when-should-i-use-events#t=201611041324198596868

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Good practice is to emit the event from child and handle the data in the parent. For example:

Dropdown-item component:

```
<a 
  class="dropdown-item" 
  @click.stop.prevent="select()">
  {{text}}
</a>

methods: {
    select() {
      this.$emit('selected', this.item)
    }
}
```

Parent component:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" v-show="!isClosed">
  <dropdown-item @selected="selectItem"><dropdown>
</div>

methods: {
    selectItem(item) {
      this.selectedItem = item
    }
}
```

For more check this in Vue.js docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Custom-Events

Comment: This wouldn't work in vue 2.0 since events no longer bubble up to the parent. You need to use an event hub now

Comment: That is not true. Check the linked docs which refers to `Vue.js 2.0`. You can emit event to the parent, but can not distribute from parent to children components anymore as it used to be in < v2

Comment: Yes good thinking, had that in mind too, but the problem is I want to use the final components nested into each other, you know what I mean? `<ui-dropdown><ui-dropdown-item></ui-dropdown-item></ui-dropdown>`

Comment: @PrimozRome looks like you are right. I must have misread the doc the first time. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @gob you mean using slots or just having a nested component inside another component? I use this pattern all the time in Vue.js 2.0 in sub-components. You can also use it inside slots. For example I have used it in slots with my modal window component, where my slot content is a sub-component which emit's different events to the main modal component...

Comment: @Primoz Rome So do you emit them with `this.$parent.emit('event')` from the sub-component? because idealy i dont want to use it like this: `<dropdown-item @selected="selectItem"><dropdown>` I want everything to be in the component

Comment: @GOB what do you mean "I want everything to be in the component"? If I understood right you have 2 components: `dropdown` and `dropdown-item`? Just emit the event from `dropdown-item` and handle it in dropdown. It's pretty straight forward like I explained in my answer.

Comment: Yes it is, but I can't really see how you can emit an event from a slot-component to the component where the slot is in... Mabey I'm missing something